# Can I declare variables/arrays inside a sed script?

Tags: linux, variables, awk, sed, scripting

I am wondering if I can declare variables inside a `sed` script. I.e. as an interpreter does `sed` have a concept of variables like C, awk, python ...
I'm *not* talking abt passing shell variables to a sed script.

E.g. following `awk` script is supposed to mask names of real customers by replacing them with Tom Dick or Harry in a sequence.

```
awk -F: '
  BEGIN{ ar[1]='Tom'; ar[2]='Dick'; ar[3]='Harry' }
  /Name:/ {
    print $1 ":" ar[i]
    if (i == 3)
      i = 1
    else
      i = i + 1;
  }
' customers.txt
```

Can I declare variables like `i` or `ar` in a `sed` script?

Comment: If you have `awk`, why use `sed`?

Comment: Read the manual for `sed`, especially the bits about the pattern space and the hold space. That's what `sed` has for "variables"...

Comment: @Jotne question is not how to accomplish something, it's to find out if `sed` supports variables or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the commenter said, there is a rudimentary construct called a hold space that you can pile on your data and pull it off, it would be easier if you use a Bash function with a case statement or if you want something somewhat intuitive you can just use shell expansion and if you don't need to iterate sequentially you can use $RANDOM:

`sed "s/Name:.*/Name: $([[ $(($RANDOM%3)) -eq 0 ]] && (echo -n "TOM") || ([[ $(($RANDOM%3)) -eq 1 ]] && echo "DICK") || echo "HARRY")/" customers.txt`